# Can coordinates declared inside "append after command+\pgfextra" command be used afterwards?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to add some lines to certain nodes but being declared within node options and I thought using `append after command` and `\pgfextra...\endpgfextra`. But new `coordinate` nodes declared inside this new path are not know outside. What can I do to use them?

Just a little example to show the problem. In next code, the command `\draw (a.antenna)--(b.antenna)` doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{antenna/.style={append after command={ 
    \pgfextra \draw (\tikzlastnode.north)--++(90:1cm) circle(2pt) coordinate (\tikzlastnode.antenna); \endpgfextra}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw node[draw, minimum width=2cm, antenna] (a) at (0,0) {A};

\draw node[draw, minimum width=2cm, antenna] (b) at (2,0) {B};

%\draw (a.antenna) -- (b.antenna);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switching the separator character `.` with something different, e.g. `@` or `_` helps:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{antenna/.style={append after command={
    \pgfextra \draw (\tikzlastnode.north)--++(90:1cm) circle(2pt) coordinate
(\tikzlastnode _antenna); \endpgfextra}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw node[draw, minimum width=2cm, antenna] (a) at (0,0) {A};

\draw node[draw, minimum width=2cm, antenna] (b) at (2,0) {B};

\draw (a_antenna) -- (b_antenna);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The dot is used for shapes, e.g.: `a.north`, `a.130`. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) says in section "17.2.1 Syntax of the Node Command":

> `/tikz/name=<node name>`       (no default)
>   Assigns a name to the node for
>   later reference. Since this is a "high-level" name (drivers never know
>   of it), you can use spaces, number, letters, or whatever you like when
>   naming a node. Thus, you can name a node just `1` or perhaps
>   `start of chart` or even `y_1`. Your node name should not contain any
>   punctuation like a dot, a comma, or a colon since these are used to
>   detect what kind of coordinate you mean when you reference a node.